# Grouping data in a certain way in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that fetches data from a table called supervisor_approvals, I want to group rows of a certain department together and leave the other department ungrouped for each labref

```
    say supervisor approval structure looks like this
    -------------------------------------------------
   labref   department
    ab        1
    ab        1
    ab        0
    ab        0
    ab        0
    xy        1
    xy        0
    xy        0
```

### After Query (Result should be)

```
labref     department

  ab          0
  ab          1
  ab          1
  xy          0
  xy          1
```

Instead it does not show other labref data just the first one as shown  [a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fb86/9](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fb86/9)!

my sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
                FROM supervisor_approvals 
                WHERE department = 0
                AND assign_status='0' 
                GROUP BY department 
                UNION ALL SELECT * 
                FROM supervisor_approvals 
                WHERE department = 1
                AND assign_status='0' 
                ORDER BY department DESC
```

Comment: why rows with id 4 and 5 are not included?

Comment: I don't understand what the "after_id" is for - or, crucially, how it relates to the '"before_id". I suspect that you may need to improve your understanding of data integrity!

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM supervisor_approvals group by labref,department
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that this is an illegal statement in standard SQL and every other DBMS will reject this statement (and apparently MySQL 5.7 will as well). Instead of rejecting this MySQL will return indeterminate (aka "random") data instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'll take those odds ;-)

Comment: In general, try to provide some explanation with your code.